# errors when install Green UML on eclipse(version 3.8) on Mac

Tags: eclipse, uml, green-uml

I am trying to install Green UML on eclipse(version 3.8), but there are some errors listed below. Anybody know how to solve it?

> "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Green 3.5.0
>   (Green.feature.group 3.5.0)   Missing requirement: Green 3.5.0
>   (Green.feature.group 3.5.0) requires 'org.eclipse.draw2d 0.0.0' but it
>   could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

When you are installing something in Eclipse, at the moment of choosing what will be installed, mark the option :

> Contact all update sites during instal to find required software

Also, you should be sure that you have all update sites set. Go to `Work With` field and check sites. You should have there:

- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/
- http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3

If you don't have these sites, write them both into the field.

The package `org.eclipse.draw2d` is one of three main components of [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/). The GEF is on the first site, so, the problem should be eliminated. You need only to revert the last installation (help-about- installation details - installation history- the previous installation - revert), restart Eclipse and repeat the installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your way to do it, but it still doesn't work. I can not even move to next step since it can not find  http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/alphonce/green.

Comment: @user3352920 And why do you install by hand? read http://green.sourceforge.net/builds.html and install normally, from the address given there.

Comment: what do you mean by installing by hand? What i did is exactly according to the link you showed. Is that right?